# How do I make two elements active, selecting each element one by one?

Tags: javascript

When clicking on each html I want to be able to activate each element class so I can see at least two activated html elements among these three boxes in my code. When clicking on the activated html element I also want to remove the active class and reset the flow.

At the moment, only one element is being set to active onclick

```js
let timeItems = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
timeItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    timeItems.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));
    this.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _"At the moment, only one element is being set to active onclick"_ - because you are first removing the class from _all_ items, before you set it on the currently clicked one. You will need to remember what the previously clicked element was - so that you can make an exception specifically for that one, inside your loop.

Comment: Hi. thx for the response, how can I remember what the previously clicked element?

Answer (score 1):

You are first removing the class from *all* items, before you set it on the currently clicked one. You will need to remember what the previously clicked element was - so that you can make an exception specifically for that one, inside your loop.

`previousItem` gets initialized with `null`.
Inside the loop, the current item is compared with `previousItem` - only if they differ, the class gets removed from the current item.
And at the end, `previousItem` is set to the current element, `this`.

```js
let timeItems = document.querySelectorAll(".box"),
  previousItem = null;
timeItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    timeItems.forEach(btn => {
      if (btn !== previousItem) {
        btn.classList.remove('active');
      }
    });
    this.classList.add('active');
    previousItem = this;
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. If you would like to toggle active on and off for each element then you can use classList.toggle('active'). And then there would be no reason to loop through your boxes a second time to remove the active class.

```
let timeItems = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
timeItems.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", function () {
        item.classList.toggle("active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thank you for all the help so far!
In addition to my question how can I reset the active class to make the class unactive class when changing row?

Eg I select two values on one row (08:00 +  +15), and when jumping to another rtow to select new values, the selected values on the row previous row with selected values has to be reset to zero (active class removed).

```js
let datetime1 = new Date("2022-04-10 08:00:00"); // Thu Sep 16 2010 13:30:58
let datetime2 = new Date("2022-04-10 16:00:00"); // Tue Aug 18 2015 14:20:48

let open = datetime1.getHours()
let close = datetime2.getHours()
let timeDiff = close - open

let newTimeValue = new Date(open)
console.log(newTimeValue)

let timeDifference = timeDiff;
let currentTimestamp = Date.parse("2022-04-10 08:00:00");


for (let i = 0; i < timeDiff; i++) {
  let date = new Date(currentTimestamp + i * (60 * 60 * 1000) );
  let timerange = document.createElement("p");
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  let span = document.createElement("span");
  let divContainer = document.createElement("div")
  let divContainerTwo = document.createElement("div")
  let spanTimeValue = document.createElement("time");
  let spanFifteen = document.createElement("time");
  let spanThirty = document.createElement("time");
  let spanFortyFive = document.createElement("time")
  
  let timeoutput = document.createTextNode(date.toLocaleString(undefined, { timeStyle: "short" }))
  let fifteen = document.createTextNode("+15");
  let thirty = document.createTextNode("+30");
  let forty = document.createTextNode("+45");
  p.setAttribute("id", "p-value");
  span.setAttribute("id","span-value");
  spanTimeValue.setAttribute("id","span-time-value");
  spanFifteen.setAttribute("id","span-fifteen");
  spanThirty.setAttribute("id","span-thirty");
  spanFortyFive.setAttribute("id","span-forty-five");
  divContainerTwo.setAttribute("id","div-container__two")
 
  spanTimeValue.className = "time_hour"
  spanFifteen.className = "time_minutes";
  spanThirty.className = "time_minutes";
  spanFortyFive.className = "time_minutes";



  document.getElementById("div-container").appendChild(spanTimeValue)
  spanTimeValue.appendChild(timeoutput)   

  document.getElementById("div-container__two").appendChild(p)
  document.getElementById("p-value").appendChild(span)
  //document.getElementById("span-value")

  spanFifteen.appendChild(fifteen)
  spanThirty.appendChild(thirty)
  spanFortyFive.appendChild(forty)


  span.appendChild(spanFifteen)
  span.appendChild(spanThirty)
  span.appendChild(spanFortyFive)
 
}

let setTime = document.querySelectorAll(".time_minutes, .time_hour"),
  previousItem = null;
  setTime.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    setTime.forEach(btn => {
      if (btn !== previousItem) {
        btn.classList.remove('active');
      }
    });
    this.classList.add('active');
    previousItem = this;
  });
  
 });
```

```css
.active {
    background:#7BB8BE;
    color: white;
  }




.box {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height:100px;
    }




#choose-time__range {
    background: #F9FCFC;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
}

#div-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


#p-value {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

      <div id="choose-time__range">
        <div id="div-container"></div>
        <div id="div-container__two"></div>
      </div>



 

    
    


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this isn't an answer, please recreated it as a question. Thank you.